# Android Google Maps - NullPointerException - Location.getLatitude()

Tags: java, android, google-maps, nullpointerexception

I'm stumped on this current issue, I'm trying to retrieve a user location from the super class to eventually assign it to a marker.  What is stumping me is how do I simply retrieve a location from the superclass?  I've got the blue dot on my MapsActivity superclass, but how do I transfer it over?

`mLastLocation` is a Location reference from the superclass

Am I on the right track?

I'm pretty new to this so any quick insights would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class CircleSizeActivity extends MapsActivity implements  OnMapReadyCallback, OnMarkerDragListener, LocationListener{

    Marker mMarkerA;
    Marker mMarkerB;
    Polyline mPolyline;
    GoogleMap mMap = getMap();
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_circle);
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }

    }

    protected void onStart() {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();

    }

    protected void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    if (checkLocationPermission() == true) {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            System.out.println(mLastLocation.getLatitude());
            System.out.println(mLastLocation.getLongitude());
        }

       }
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady (GoogleMap googleMap){
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        if ((ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    }
}
```

Updated with superclass

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener, OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
Circle circle1;




CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map_activity);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);







}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    //Initialize Google Play Services
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    } else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}



@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;
    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }

    //Place current location marker
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Position").draggable(true);
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
    mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    //move map camera
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

    //stop location updates
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }


}

public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;

public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Asking user if explanation is needed
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);


        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted. Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }

            } else {

                // Permission denied, Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you actually instantiate `mLastLocation`?  I don't see this anywhere.

Comment: Thank you! Just edited my post to include MapsActivity.  I

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you! Just edited my post to include MapsActivity.  I

Comment: Why are you requesting location updates in `onConnected` then removing them at the end of `onLocationChanged`? Wouldn't you only get one location at max that way?

Comment: @SammyT  I guess my logic was to save some battery life.  Thank you for pointing that out.  I went ahead and commented out to give it a try and the same error presents itself.

Comment: @TJBlack31 You should add the logcat to your question when your code crashes like this

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you wouldn't have it all in one activity but my suggestion is to make `mLastLocation` public or protected.

Inside your `MapsActivity`:

```
public Location mLastLocation;
```

Comment: Considering you can only have one Activity open at once, I don't see how a public or protected member variable would help.

Comment: Well that's the thing, one activity seems to be extending the other.

Comment: Which makes sense in some cases, but not really the code that is shown.

Comment: @cricket_007 I agree,  Should I just restrain everything to one activity if I want the map to do two different things ("activities")? I'm just trying to figure out how to write classes and have it change that single maps functionality, but I don't want to overload this one activity with too much code.

Comment: @TJBlack31 Depends on your use cases. One can have one Activity and two SupportMapFragments that you would "toggle between"

Comment: @cricket_007 Excellent!  Just so I can see your point, other than my primary MapsActivity,  I could make any separate Activity extend SupportMapFragment if i want it to use the same map?  Thanks again

Comment: @TJBlack31 `Activity extend SupportMapFragment` doesn't make sense; activities dont extend fragments. And you dont need to extend that fragment class unless you really, really need to extend the functionality it already provides.

Comment: @cricket_007 ok, so if I wanted to create a separate class that can move objects on the map (in MapsActivity), such as markers, let's call it MarkerMover, what would that class declaration look like on its own and what would some potential instance variables look like to bind it to my original fragment? Thanks -T